# URL Re Writing issue double http issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I am having a issue with my urls google have crawled double http for example

http://example.com/example.com/c-title-id.html

and all the interlinked pages like that

please can any one help me out to redirect all the urls with 301 with .htacess

My htacess code is

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule category-([0-9]+)-(.*)-([0-9]+)\.html$ category.php?cid=$1&name=$2&page=$3.php [L]
RewriteRule search-(.*)-([0-9]+)\.html$ search.php?term=$1&page=$2.php [L]
RewriteRule all-covers-([0-9]+)\.html$ all-covers.php?page=$1.php [L]
RewriteRule index-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?page=$1.php [L]
RewriteRule featured-covers-([0-9]+)\.html$ featured-covers.php?page=$1.php [L]
RewriteRule top-downloaded-([0-9]+)\.html$ top-downloaded.php?page=$1.php [L]
RewriteRule c-([0-9]+)(.*)\.html$ cover.php?id=$1&name=$2.php [L]
RewriteRule sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
RewriteRule sitemap1.xml$ sitemap1.php [L]
RewriteRule rss.xml$ rss.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

I want to redirect all of them automaticaly.

Comment: like http://example.com/http://example.com/c-title-id to http://example.com/c-title-id

Comment: How is the URL on your question you say `http://example.com/example.com/c-title-id.html` on your comment you say `http://example.com/http://example.com/c-title-id` you need to know exactly what it is.

Comment: http://example.com/example.com/c-title-id.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be as simple as having this at the top of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule example\.com/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#... rest of your rules...
```

Comment: But now it redirects to 404

Comment: @user2998120 did you append your old rules below the code above where it says `#... rest of your rules...`?

Comment: yes i did i also checked from header status checker is it save if i enter my url over here

Comment: Does `example.com/c-title-id.html` **without the rule above** works or it redirects you to `example.com/example.com/c-title-id.html`?

Comment: By the way I forgot to mention this, but you will need to clear your cache and preferable use a different browser to test if the URL is working because its a `301` redirect so you could have been cached from your previous URLs

Comment: Really sory it was my mistake it is working perfect thank you very much thumbs up love you :D